# Proving $(A\setminus B) \times(C\setminus D)= \left((A\times C)\setminus(B\times D)\right)\setminus(A\times D)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> I was looking through some of my old questions on MSE, and found this one contained an important typo. If we change the first appearance of set $D$ on the R.H.S. of $$(A\setminus B) \times(C\setminus D)= \left((A\times C)\setminus(B\times D)\right)\setminus(A\times D)$$ to $C$ so that $$(A\setminus B) \times(C\setminus D)= \left((A\times C)\setminus(B\times C)\right)\setminus(A\times D)$$ then the equality holds, right? I figured this question will be more useful for others if it's correct since this is a prominent textbook question.

I want to show for sets $A,B,C,D$ that $$(A\setminus B) \times(C\setminus D)= \left((A\times C)\setminus(B\times D)\right)\setminus(A\times D)$$

There is a nice "proof without words" so to speak using a coordinate plane for this, and probably a proof using set algebra. But I was hoping to prove it precisely using element chasing, with biconditionals if possible. I have written my proof that way, the non expository way, and I was hoping to see if anyone could check the proof and/or comment on the logical progression.

**Proof:**

Let $x=(s,t)\in(A\setminus B) \times(C\setminus D)$. This is equivalent to $s\in(A\setminus B)$ and $t\in(C\setminus D)$

\begin{split}
 & \iff (s\in A\text{ and } s\notin B)\text{ and } (t\in C\text{ and } t\notin D) \\
 & \iff (s\in A\text{ and } s\notin B)\text{ and } t\in C, \text{ and } (s\in A\text{ and } s\notin B)\text{ and } t\notin D \\
 & \iff (s\in A\text{ and } t\in C)\text{ and } (s\notin B\text{ and } t\in C),\text{ and } (s\in A\text{ and } t\notin D)\text{ and } (s\notin B\text{ and } t\notin D) \\
 & \iff (s\in A\text{ and } t\in C)\text{ and } (s\notin B \text{ or } t\notin C), \text{ and } (s\in A\text{ and } t\notin D)\text{ and } (s\notin B\text{ and } t\notin D)\\
 & \iff (s\in A\text{ and } t\in C)\text{ and } (s\notin B \text{ or } t\notin C), \text{ and } (s\in A\text{ and } t\notin D) \\
 & \iff (s\in A\text{ and } t\in C)\text{ and } (s\notin B \text{ or } t\notin C), \text{ and } (s\notin A\text{ or } t\notin D) \\
 & \iff x=(s,t)\in(A\times C)\text{ and } x=(s,t)\notin(B\times C), \text{ and } x=(s,t)\notin(A\times D) \\
 & \iff x= (s,t) \in((A\times C)\setminus (B\times C)), \text{ and } x= (s,t)\notin(A\times D) \\
 & \iff x=(s,t)\in \left((A\times C)\setminus(B\times D)\right)\setminus(A\times D)
\end{split}
$\blacksquare$

The first through fourth line follow from the definition of the cartesian product, the definition of set difference, and double distribution of the logical connectives, respectively.

The fifth line follows from the fourth since we can relax the condition $(s\notin B \text{ and } t\in C)$ to $(s\notin B\text{ or } t\notin C)$ since the first condition is true only if $s\notin B$, which alone makes the second condition true.

The sixth line follows from the fifth, i.e. simply ignoring the last condition since it's redundant, because we already know $s\notin B$ from the second condition and that $t\notin D$ from the second to last condition.

The seventh line follows from the sixth line since the last condition there only hinges on $t\notin D$ being true since we know from the first condition that $s\in A$ regardless.

And the rest follows from unwinding the definitions of Cartesian product and set difference.

Is this proof sound? I used [this nifty Stanford Truth Table generator](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/) to help check logical equivalences along the way.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something, the assertion is false.

What if $s$ is an element of both $A$ and $B$ and

$t$ is an element of $C$ but not of $D$.

Then $(s,t)$ is excluded from the LHS but is not excluded from the RHS.

Comment: I believe you are correct. $A=\{1,2\},B=\{1\},C=\{1\},D=\{2\},s=1,t=1$ then $(A-B)\times(C-D)=\{2\}\times\{1\}=\{(2,1)\}$ and $RHS=\{(1,1),{2,1}\} - \{(1,2)\} - \{(1,2),(2,2)\}=\{(1,1),(2,1)\}$.

Comment: It seems that $LHS\subseteq RHS$, which would agree with the other answer by SacAndSac

Comment: @GarethMa How can $s$ be an element of both $A$ and $B$ if $s\in(A\setminus B)$?

Comment: @upanddownintegrate You are misinterpreting the comment of GarethMa.  Let $M$ denote the set of all ordered pairs $(s,t)$, where $s \in (A \cap B)$ and $t \in (C \cap [\neg D]).$  What GarethMa's comment is referring to is that every element in the LHS is in the RHS and that every element in the RHS is in the LHS, **except** the elements in the set $M$.  The elements in the RHS that are not in the LHS are specifically equal to the set $M$.

Comment: @user2661923 I apologize, I was actually replying to your question of “What if $s$ is an element of both $A$ and $B$” and accidentally tagged GarethMa. His example though does demonstrate that they are not equal, sadly. I wonder where this is accounted for in the picture I drew.

Comment: @upanddownintegrate What picture?

Comment: @user2661923 I have added the diagram above in my question (ignore the coloring of the non shaded boxes).

Comment: @upanddownintegrate In your diagram, the 4th column from the left represents $(A \cap B)$.  The bottom 3 rows represent $(C \cap [\neg D])$.  Then, the pertinent ordered pairs $(s,t)$ are represented by the 3 cells that are in the 4th column from the left and the bottom 3 rows.

Answer (score 1):

In your fifth line, you use
$$s\not\in B\text{ and }t\in C\Leftrightarrow s\not\in B\text{ or }t\notin C,$$
which is not especially true (only $\Rightarrow$ is always true).